# Does order in bind() matter?

Tags: r, ggplot2, rbind

I am having a problem with ggplot plotting histogram of two different data sets.

Imagine I have two tables:

```
histClick = {
id   length
1       4
2       6
3       3
4       2
5       2
6       2
7       2
8       3
9      12
10      2
11      3
12      3
13      3
14      2
15      2
16      4
}

histTest = {
id length
1      3
2      2
3      3
4      4
5      6
6      2
7      4
8      2
}
```

I add another column to each table with this:

```
histClick[, "cat"] <- "Click"
histTest[, "cat"] <- "Test"`
```

Here is the problem. When I want to bind these two tables together in one data frame, it seems like the order becomes important and affects the output. the output of ggplot is different between `total <- rbind(histTest, histClick)` and `total <- rbind(histClick, histTest)` in the following:

```
sessions <- as.factor(total$cat)
ggplot(total, aes(total$length, fill = sessions)) + 
    geom_histogram(binwidth = .2) +
    facet_grid(cat ~ ., margins = TRUE, scales = "free")
```

For `total <- rbind(histClick, histTest)`:
[image]

For `total <- rbind(histTest, histClick)`:
[image]

My questions:
1- Why should I get a different results in a way that `rbind` works? Does order matter?

2- How I should I get a correct answer in whatever order I put my data?

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The difference results from R's recycling rules.  The two data frames that you combined are not of the same length.  To show the difference I used the following two data frames, the only difference being the order of `rbind`:

```
dput(total2)
structure(list(id = structure(c(1L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
13L, 14L, 15L), .Label = c("1", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", 
"15", "16", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "id"), class = "factor"), 
    length = c(4, 5, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4, 
    3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 4, 2), cat = c("Click", "Click", "Click", 
    "Click", "Click", "Click", "Click", "Click", "Click", "Click", 
    "Click", "Click", "Click", "Click", "Click", "Click", "Test", 
    "Test", "Test", "Test", "Test", "Test", "Test", "Test")), .Names = c("id", 
"length", "cat"), row.names = c("2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", 
"8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "21", 
"31", "41", "51", "61", "71", "81", "91"), class = "data.frame")

dput(total)
structure(list(id = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 17L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
"id", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "9"), class = "factor"), 
    length = c(2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
    6, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3), cat = c("Test", "Test", "Test", 
    "Test", "Test", "Test", "Test", "Test", "Click", "Click", 
    "Click", "Click", "Click", "Click", "Click", "Click", "Click", 
    "Click", "Click", "Click", "Click", "Click", "Click", "Click"
    )), .Names = c("id", "length", "cat"), row.names = c("2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "21", "31", "41", "51", "61", 
"71", "81", "91", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17"
), class = "data.frame")
```

Then I created the two panel plots:

```
sessions <- as.factor(total2$cat)
ggplot(total2, aes(x = id, y = length, fill = cat)) + 
  geom_histogram(stat = "identity") +
  facet_grid(cat ~ ., margins = TRUE, scales = "free")
```

[image]

```
sessions <- as.factor(total$cat)
ggplot(total, aes(total$length, fill = sessions)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth = .2) +
  facet_grid(cat ~ ., margins = TRUE, scales = "free")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have added the image I get for each binding. However your answer showed an interesting point, I didn't offer any solution to the problem and how to address it.

Comment: You solve it by having the same number of ids in each data frame.  Try subseting histClick to the first 8 ids and I suspect you will find that the order of rbind doesn't matter for the resulting plots.

Comment: What if I want a different size of data frames? What's the solution?